# MySQL Error Code 1215: cannot add foreign constraints

Tags: mysql

I encountered error code 1215: "cannot add foreign key constraints" when creating table, I tried the following methods, they all failed

1. check whether two varable in different table have the same type
2. set EIGINE to InnoDB and set all the same CHARSET
3. check if you try to reference variables that haven't `key` or `unique`
4. `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;` to disable checking.
5. spelling error

I also use `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;` try to find some error message, but it is just a simple "cannot add foreign key constraints".I'm new to sql, so I really don't know what I am doing wrong.Can someone help or specify the cause of the error?

This is my sql code

```sql
CREATE TABLE book(
  book_id char (50),
  book_title char (50),
  PRIMARY KEY (book_title)
) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = latin1;

CREATE TABLE customer(
  book_title char (50) ,
  customer_id char (50),
  PRIMARY KEY (customer_id),
  foreign key (book_title) references book
) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = latin1;
```

Comment: Please do a full error messages  - customer (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"). Fairly easy answer, the `book` reference needs to specify which book column. e.g.
[fldde](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=16a3d2dd8d80cb15c73dfbd8bb0f8719). Also note the using of `book_id` as an `int` type rather than title being a PK.

Comment: Reading manuals like [MariaDB's FK](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/foreign-keys/) and MySQL [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) actually has decent description and examples.

Comment: oh, thanks@danblack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please create child table like below as ***reference column of parent table*** is missing:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE customer(
  book_id int unsigned not null,
  customer_id char (50),
  PRIMARY KEY (customer_id),
  foreign key (book_id) references book (book_id)
) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = latin1;
```